# Github: unable to push to origin from desktop app

Tags: github

I am using GitHub desktop app. I have cloned locally, made some changes, committed locally and trying to push to remote.

I get the following error:

> Authentication failed: you may not have permission to access or the
>   repository may have been archived. Open options and verify that you've
>   signed in with an account that has permission to access this
>   repository.

Need some directions as I am lost ...

Comment: Is repo is your own or someone else's?, check this once: https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/

Comment: its my own. I see that user name at GitHub and local are same

Comment: okay, when you are trying to push to remote, does it prompted username and password?

Comment: no, it does not. Just takes a while trying to push and then the above message

Comment: hmm, its wierd for repository you own. Could not think of anyhting else.

Comment: if its possible, can you share your public repo url here?

Comment: sure https://github.com/sharanbr/assorted_verification

Comment: I could see some of the commits, was it working before and now it's not working?

Comment: i think those commits are the ones i did using browser. Since working over browser is tedious, i installed GitHub desktop and facing this issue. Do I need to do some setting either in GitHub repo or local?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181021/discussion-between-dkb-and-sharanbr).